# How can I send mail to Gmail with an attachment, in Perl?

Tags: perl, email, gmail, attachment

How can I send mail to Gmail using Perl? Here's what I'm trying:

```
my $mailer = Email::Send->new(
    {
        mailer      => 'SMTP::TLS',
        mailer_args => [
            Host     => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            Port     => 587,
            User     => 'xxx',
            Password => 'xxx',
        ]
    }
);

use Email::Simple::Creator;    # or other Email::

use File::Slurp;
@arrIrc = read_file("$ircFile");
my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        From    => 'xxx',
        To      => "$configList{email}",
        Subject => "The summary of logfile $channelName",
    ],
    body => "@arrIrc",
);
```

Comment: To Gmail and with Gmail(That is once i authenticate to gmail and then send mails to other accounts using this gmail)

Comment: I were able to send mail without attachment. In the next comment I am going to upload the script.

Comment: my $mailer = Email::Send->new( {
       mailer => 'SMTP::TLS',
       mailer_args => [
           Host => 'smtp.gmail.com',
           Port => 587,
           User => 'hari.sujith@gmail.com',
           Password => 'xxx',
       ]
    });

    use Email::Simple::Creator; # or other Email::
    use File::Slurp;
    @arrIrc = read_file("$ircFile");
    my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        From    => 'hari.sujith@gmail.com',
        To      => "$configList{email}",
        Subject => "The summary of logfile $channelName",
    ],
    body => "@arrIrc",
    );

Answer (score 5):

Use [Net::SMTP::SSL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::SMTP::SSL) to talk to GMail.

See [MIME::Lite inline images](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=784574) on [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org) for an example.

Comment: SMTP is for transport. If you have a correctly formatted message (Mime-Lite can help you with that), then it will happily send whatever you hand it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send mail to Gmail, you do the same thing you would do to send mail anywhere. If you want to send mail through Gmail, there is the [Email::Send::Gmail](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-Send-Gmail/) module. Merely typing your question in Google led me to [Sending Mail Through Gmail with Perl](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/sending-mail-through-gmail-with-perl/) by Mark Sanborn.

Comment: Unfortunately, the article by Mark uses Net::SMTP::TLS which is badly broken and unmaintained. For instance, it will duplicate & cripple your attachments if you try to add them. There is now Net::SMTP::TLS::ButMaintained which works, but causes a severe namespace pollution. See http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SMTP::TLS::ButMaintained

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME::Lite) to compose a message, which you then send to your local sendmail process.  However, in order to talk to gmail's servers you need to [have SSL certificates set up](http://download.gna.org/hpr/fetchmail/FAQ/gmail-pop-howto.html).  There's probably more detailed instructions for that on [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: So you mean to say that once the SSL certificates are set up manually then I can send mail with attachment using MIME::Lite to gmail (provided I had given username and password of gmail account). Right?